# awk: how to print the echo filename with the conditionally found variable

Tags: loops, printing, awk, filenames

I am searching thorough 38 independent files to find a data point that satisfies two conditions using a loop in awk. I would like to print the echo name in column 1 and the found data point in column 2 of the output file test3.tsv.

I have tried this loop and expression statement.

```
filename=echo
for ID in {001..038}
do
    echo "FLD0$ID"
cat /new-data/filtered/FLD0${ID}.filtered.tsv | awk '{ if($1 == "chr15" && $2 ==39074782 ) { OFS = "\t" ; print FILENAME, $4}}' >>/new-data/filtered/test3.tsv
 done;
```

Unfortunately my output file test3.tsv looks like:

```
    -   37
    -   45
    -   96
    -   10
    -   21
    -   75
```

Where I get a "-" instead of the expected FLD0001...FLD0038.  I understand that I am probably getting a "-" because no specific file name is provided.  How do I get the output of the echo statement to replace the "-" in test3.tsv?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the filename to awk as an argument instead of piping its contents to it:

```
for ID in {001..038}
do
    echo "FLD0$ID"
    awk '{if ($1 == "chr15" && $2 == 39074782) {OFS = "\t" ; print FILENAME, $4}}' /new-data/filtered/FLD0${ID}.filtered.tsv >>/new-data/filtered/test3.tsv
done
```

You could also move the setting of `OFS` into a `BEGIN` block to avoid setting it each time you have output:

```
for ID in {001..038}
do
    echo "FLD0$ID"
    awk 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"} {if ($1 == "chr15" && $2 == 39074782) {print FILENAME, $4}}' /new-data/filtered/FLD0${ID}.filtered.tsv >>/new-data/filtered/test3.tsv
done
```

Comment: you could even avoid the `for` loop and say `awk '...' FLD0{001..038}.filtered.tsv`

Comment: Hi Steve, I tried the 1st code you provided and I get the file name as the variable in column 1.  I wonder if it is possible to improve upon that and only get the  FLD001-FLD038 as the variable in column 1 without the entire path to the file as the variable?

Comment: Sure, see [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134219). Just change the awk statement to `awk 'function basename(f) {sub(".*/","",f); return f} BEGIN {OFS = "\t"} {if ($1 == "chr15" && $2 == 39074782) {print basename(FILENAME), $4}}' /new-data/filtered/FLD0${ID}.filtered.tsv >>/new-data/filtered/test3.tsv` .

Comment: Hi Steve, Could you explain what sub(".*/","",f) is doing? It seems that is is 3 elements?  I would also like to remove the ".filtered.tsv" from the name too. and just have the FLD number.

Comment: Sure, in this case `sub` matches the pattern `".*/"`, which means "any character up to and including a '/'", against the third argument `f`, and replaces the match with the empty string `""`. The match is greedy, i.e., it matches the largest amount of text possible. This means that if `f` is a filename like `/a/b/c/d` the pattern will match everything except `d`, effectively stripping off all directories and leaving only the base filename. To do what you want means adding another call to `sub` after the existing one: just add `sub(".filtered.tsv","",f);` before `return f`.

Comment: Hi Steve, that worked well. Exactly what I wanted to to and with a understandable explanation.